# Any function to get elements in common in two arrays?

Tags: php

Is there any function that does the inverse operation of `array_diff()`?

I mean, if i have:

```
array(1,2,3)
array(3,4,5)
```

I would like that function returns `array(3)`, or directly `3`.

Note: `array_intersect()` doesn't fit me.

Javier

Comment: Why not? `array_intersect()` does exactly what you want.

Comment: Leaving a note that says "the function that does precisely what I want doesn't fit me" without any elaborating comments is not exactly the right way to go about asking for help.

Comment: Except from what you have provided, `array_intersect()` does work: http://codepad.org/8uis96MM There's two versions of it in the paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  `array_intersect() doesn't fit me` is because it returns:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 3
)
```

and not:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
)
```

or
`3`

Then you could easily transform the array to something workable with [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
<?php 
$arr1 = array(1,2,3);
$arr2 = array(3,4,5);

$new = array_values(array_intersect($arr1,$arr2));
$new = $new[0];
print_r($new); //3
?>
```

Else please explain your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) this will computes the intersection of arrays

Comment: OP Doesn't want array_intersect. Read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use `array_intersect()`, check this inefficient method:

```
$arr1= array(1,2,3);
$arr2= array(3,4,5);

function arr_intersect($array1, $array2)
{
    $array_result=array();
    $array_shared = array_diff($array1+$array2, array_diff($array1, $array2));
    $count=count($array_shared);

    return array_values($array_shared);
}

print_r(arr_intersect($arr1, $arr2));
```